# Is partial correlation analysis in spss reasonable

Tags: correlation, spss, partial-correlation

I had two continuous variables, neither of which were in line with normal distribution. spearman correlation analysis found moderate positive correlation (r=0.597). Then `spss` was used for partial correlation analysis, and the control variable included was platelets (continuous variable). The results given by `spss` seem to be based on Pearson correlation coefficient, which shows that the results are not correlated.
I have the following doubts: 1. Is this partial correlation correct? 2. How can I make adjustments if it is not correct? thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Several things.

First, Pearson's correlation $r$ does not strictly assume normality of the variables themselves (e.g., for interpretation). The normality assumptions only comes into play when conducting significance testing.

Second, nothing you provided supports your doubts concerning the low/non-existent partial correlation. Remember, the partial correlation is a technique used to describe the linear relationship between two continuous variables while controlling for the effects of one or more other variables. In light of this, what your results show is that when controlling for platelets, the correlation between your two continuous variables diminishes. No purely statistical adjustment can help you. That being said, maybe there are some unmeasured variables (or variables you did not include in your analysis) that can shed some light on this.

Third, as suggested by your question, it seems you think that the smaller size of your partial correlation, compared to your Spearman correlation, may be due to the former relying on Pearson's $r$. This factor probably contributes to the difference, although I cannot provide a definitive explanation without access to your data. Though one thing you could try is to calculate a partial rank correlation, which can be done in `SPSS` (see [this](https://www.ibm.com/support/pages/partial-rank-correlations-spss) link for more details).

Finally, for more information on correlation, I highly recommend [Miles & Shevlin (2001)](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0761962301).

**References**

Miles, J., & Shevlin, M. (2001). Applying regression and correlation: A guide for students and researchers. Sage.